# Upgrade existing farm to .NET 4.5.1?

Tags: 2013

I can't find any useful documentation on how to do this.  I have 4.5.1 SDK installed on my development environment, but when I create a new sharepoint project I can only select 4.5:

[image: 4.5.1]

[image: 4.5]

Help is much appreciated!

**EDIT:**

This issue only seems to be affecting my SharePoint project templates.  I can select 4.5.1 on other types of projects:

[image: 4.5.1classlib]

Comment: Is this affecting only Sharepoint Project templates? Have you tried with other types of templates?

Comment: Yes, only SharePoint project templates.  I can select 4.5.1 (among others) for other types of projects.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have installed the Microsoft .NET 4.5.1 Developer pack

https://support.microsoft.com/kb/2878632

It contains the .NET Framework 4.5.1 Multi-Targeting Pack which contains the reference assemblies needed to build apps that target the .NET Framework 4.5.1.

Comment: It is installed, as shown in my screenshot.  I can create projects targeting 4.5.1, but not SharePoint ones.